# Kwicks slider images with text

Tags: kwicks

Hello  (I am not a programmer so bear with me)

I am using drupal 7.  My boss loves the KWICKS slider.  I have gotten this to work but only with images using views-kwicks module.

I would like to be able to have text(teaser) placed over the images in the slider with a link to the corresponding page when clicked, like http://demo.themesmania.com/creative/kwicks-slider

How should I go about doing this?  Thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

the markup used in that link is:

put this inside your `<li></li>` of kwicks:

```
<div class="slide-description">
<h4>At vero eos et accusamus et</h4>
<p>At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti</p>
</div>
```

then use this css:

```
.slide-description { background-color:#000;
    bottom: 0;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: block;
    font-weight: normal;
    left: 0;
    line-height: normal;
    padding: 16px 20px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 760px;z-index: 2;}
```